# Creating a subset of an array in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

My data file looks like

```
---
data:
  - item 1
  - item 2
  - item 3
  - item 4
```

I want to include a taskbook for item 1 and a diferent taskbook for item 2 - 4. How can I create an array with just ['item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4']

```
---
- hosts: localhost
tasks:
  - include: taskbooks1.yml param={{data[0]}}

  - include: taskbooks2.yml param={{item}}
    with_indexed_items: "{{ data }}" # I want to pass another list without item 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- include: taskbooks2.yml param={{item}}
  with_items: "{{data[1:]}}"
```